# Missing frameworks after upgrading to Xcode 4.4.1

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I upgraded to Xcode 4.4.1. Now, I'm trying to add framework QuartzCore.framework, but getting Quartz.framework not found while running the application on device and it is working fine on simulator.

After analyzing, I got, the framework is missing at the path:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk/
```

Even if , it is available at:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/
```

Can anyone please let me know, what is going wrong? How to solve the problem?

Comment: Why not upgrade to Xcode 4.5.1 which is the current version?

Comment: Yes, I'll upgrade it to latest xcode 4.5.1. But as I am in middle of something and unable to debug the code on device. So can you please let me know, any solution to rectify the issue.  Thanks

Comment: I think updating to the current and supported versions should be the very first step in trying to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you're developing for iOS, you'll probably want **QuartzCore.framework** (and not Quartz.framework).

Answer (score 0):

Try re-adding QuarzCore in Linked Libraries under Build Phases. If you're using a 6.0 device, you'll need to update Xcode to 4.5 or later.